# Equivalent events

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Define the term "equivalent events". If $M$ is the event that the number rolled from a die is a prime number, which event can be equivalent to $M$?

Comment: Unless you can give us some context even to understand what is meant by "equivalent events," Georgia, we will need to close this as an incomprehensible question.

Answer (score 1):

The possible outcomes for the roll are $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. The primes in this set are $\{2, 3, 5\}$, so the event $M$ is in a single roll of a die a 2, 3, or 5 is rolled. I haven't seen a definition of "equivalent event", but if I were to hazard a guess, I would say that 2 events are "equivalent" if they have the same probability distribution. Since $M$ has a 50:50 probability distribution (assuming a fair die), it is equivalent to a coin flip.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2, 3 and 5 are the primes in the set of integers from 1 to 6, rolling a 2 or 3 or a 5 is equivalent to rolling a prime.

Comment: I understand an 'event' to be a measurable set, but obviously you cannot be asserting that $\{2,3,5\}$ is the same as $\{3\}$ or $\{5\}$, or even has the same probability.  What, then, do *you* mean by equivalent?  (The question probably comes down to the definition of "equivalent." I would argue that the question is ill-posed and cannot be answered as is because "equivalent" has so many common definitions.)

Comment: so how do we define 'equivalent events'?

Comment: I am taking equivalent to me different ways of expressing identical events.  So in the example occurrence of a prime is the same as saying a 3 or a 5 occurs.  We have a very simple discrete probability measure here.  A roll of the die will yield 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6  with probabilities p$_1$ to P$_6$ summing to 1 and usually assuming a balanced die p$_i$ equals 1/6 for each i.

Comment: 2 is prime. I agree that rolling a 3 is equivalent to rolling a 5 in this event space, but I don't think rolling a 3 is equivalent to $M$, because $M$ is 2 or 3 or 5.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the only even prime! I edited my answer accordingly.